# Blazor one-way binding from child to parent component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I would like to ask whether it is possible to implement one-way binding from child to parent component. Meaning that when I change property in child component it also changes in parent component but when I change property in parent component it doesn't change in child component.

In ParentComponent.razor I want to have:

```
    <ChildComponent @bind-one-way-Token="Token">
```

I know that in Blazor I can implement Two-Way binding via implementation of Property + PropertyChanged event. But two way binding is not suitable for my use case. I know I can pass value from child component to parent component via EventCallback / StateContainer, but these are not as elegant as binding.

Comment: I think you are stuck with "non-elagant" EventCallback.

Comment: _"when I change property in parent component it doesn't change in child component"_ then why is it the same (bound) property?   This is a strange requirement.

Comment: Hi @HH . Because I've implemented ReCaptcha component. And when ReCaptcha is validated it returns Token string. And I want this token string to be passed to parent component. Which most likely will be some kind of form. So OnValidation of that form I can check if ReCaptcha token is present. And since I want to pass token only FROM ReCaptcha component not TO recaptcha component that's why I got idea for One-Way binding. So I can bind to it as to any other form property, but it can be only changed from ReCaptcha component.

Comment: When you do the initialization right this could still be normal binding with `@bind-Value` , but it seems you want notification (EventCallback) , not binding.

Comment: EventCallback is the way because a "bind" is a "prop" + "eventcallback" too